# bless --nextonly parameter fails

Tags: bootcamp, bless

I am using the bless command to reboot my Mac mini into VMware ESX.

```
sudo bless --device /dev/disk3s1 --setboot --nextonly && sudo reboot
```

Booting ESX works but after the next reboot the Mac reboots into ESX again, despite the "--nextonly" parameter.

The same command (with a different device) works for rebooting into Windows on the Boot Camp partition once, i.e. after booting into Windows the Mac mini reboots into OS X again. But it doesn't work with booting into ESX.

Any ideas?

Update: With the --legacy switch the nvram variable is changed to boot from USB and uses the BIOS emulator, which promptly boots from the Windows partition. So that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `--legacy` flag:

```
sudo bless --device /dev/disk3s1 --legacy --setboot --nextonly reboot
```

*(not sure why you're using the && operator; try the command without it)*

I encountered a similar issue a while back; the `--legacy` flag apparently was needed due to the EFI compatibility at the time. Apple's man page reads:

> ```
> --legacy     If --setBoot is given, set the firmware to boot a legacy BIOS-based
>              operating system from the specified disk. The active flag of an
>              MBR-partitioned disk is not modified, which can be done with fdisk(8).
>              This is only supported on EFI-based systems.
> ```

In VMWare ESX you will need to have EFI selected in the boot manager. It's possible that creating a boot.efi file could help solve your issue as well.

-> **[bless](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/bless.8.html)** (OS X Man Pages)

Comment: I read the man page. Seems to me that --legacy is for BIOS-based boot loaders (i.e. those that think they were started by an IBM BIOS). But ESX boots from an EFI partition. Surely an EFI partition must be booted without the legacy flag?

Comment: I tried the legacy flag. It switched to BIOS mode and ultimately causes the Mac to boot the Windows partition (even though the nvram variable was set to USB).

Comment: did you try booting without the `--legacy` flag as well as `&&` operator at the end? `sudo bless --device /dev/disk3s1 --setboot --nextonly reboot`

Comment: Yes, I started with booting without the legacy parameter. Still don't know what the "reboot" parameter is as I cannot find it in the man page. What do you mean about the && operator?